# rundeck 2.6.8.1 can't change default admin/admin

Tags: rundeck

I've tried to create new admin pass with:

```
java -cp jetty-all-7.6.0.v20120127.jar org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Password admin 'pass'
```

and copy to realm.properties like this:

```
admin: CRYPT:pass-string,server-administrator,content-administrator,admin
```

and also comment the `framework.server.username` and `framework.server.password` lines in `framework.properties` file.

I've restarted rundeckd, but still i'm able to login to the GUI with admin/admin.

What i'm missing here?

Comment: What was wrong before.. ?? Normally it's never been an issue once you edited the realm properties file...

Answer (score 7):

You can change the default admin password in rundeck with this commands:

```
# generate a random password
RD_PASS=$(openssl rand -base64 16)

# show unencrypted password
echo ${RD_PASS}

# generate MD5 sum
RD_PASS_MD5=$(java -cp /var/lib/rundeck/bootstrap/jetty-all-9.0.7.v20131107.jar org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Password admin ${RD_PASS} 2>&1 | grep MD5)

# change default rundeck admin password
sed -i "s/^admin:admin/admin:${RD_PASS_MD5}/g" /etc/rundeck/realm.properties

# restart rundeck
service rundeckd restart
```

Answer (score 3):

You should put MD5 string after admin username instead of CRYPT string.